# How do I add a Google account to my online accounts settings?

Tags: unity, google, online-accounts

I seem to remember being able to add a Google account in the past. However, that does not seem to be an option now:

[image]

Do I need to install some plugin to get Google account support?

Answer (score 3):

How to add Google:

1. Open a terminal
2. Type the following command, then press enter: `sudo apt-get install account-plugin-google`
3. Type `y` when it asks you if you want to install it
4. You are done