# Online Google Account Bug

Tags: 16.04, online-accounts

I am using ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I was trying to add google account (online account), after entering account and password it ask for permission, i click on allow and online account windows get black and it stuck. Won't go any further. What should i do ?

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't understand your question. You want to add a Google account.. where? To what? And what does the OS has to do with it?

Comment: I want to add google account as in online accounts.

Comment: OK then. Well, I haven't try it myself, but maybe the information from this question can help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/699255/how-do-i-add-a-google-account-to-my-online-accounts-settings

Comment: Or better this one : http://askubuntu.com/questions/505852/why-wont-my-ubuntu-gnome-accept-my-google-password (Sorry, if they are not similar to your problem, but maybe you can get an idea from them.)

Comment: Also, check on this:  https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2152542

Comment: I tried but they all posted same problem and no solution. Still thank you for the effort.